# Spring Kafka giving only 1st message from batch to @KafkaListener method

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We have spring Kafka application with a customer deserializer class and we are using @KafkaListener annotation to receive messages. We noticed that we are reading expected number of messages in a batch(of batch size 5) by adding a log statement in the custom deserializer but the method annotated with @KafkaListener is getting only the first message from that batch.

here is out Kafka config

```
package com.aa.ctlctr.processor.config;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.SaslConfigs;
import org.apache.kafka.common.header.Header;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;

import com.aa.opshub.msgnode.flight.event.json.model.Flight;

@EnableKafka
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.yml")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class KafkaSourceConfig {
    
    private static Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(KafkaSourceConfig.class);
    
    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers")
    private String brokerConnect;
    
    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit}")
    private boolean enableAutocommit;
    
    @Value("${spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode}")
    private String groupIdConfig;    
    
    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.records:5}")
    private String maxPollRecordConfig;
    
    @Value("${spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol}")
    private String securityProtocol;
      
    @Value("${spring.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism}")
    private String saslMechanism;
    
    @Value("${spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config}")
    private String saslJaasConfig;
    
    @Value("${spring.kafka.properties.sasl.login.callback.handler.class}")
    private String saslClientCallbackHandlerClass;
    
    
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumer_Configs() {
        Map<String, Object> prop = new HashMap<>();
        prop.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokerConnect);
        prop.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        prop.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaCustomDeserializer.class);
        prop.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, enableAutocommit);
        prop.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupIdConfig);
        prop.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, maxPollRecordConfig);
        prop.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, securityProtocol);
        prop.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, saslMechanism);
        prop.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, saslJaasConfig);
        prop.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_CLIENT_CALLBACK_HANDLER_CLASS, saslClientCallbackHandlerClass);
        prop.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, saslJaasConfig);
        prop.put("ssl.engine.factory.class", InsecureSslEngineFactory.class);
        return prop;
    }


    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Flight> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumer_Configs(),new StringDeserializer(), 
                  new KafkaCustomDeserializer<>());

    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Flight> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Flight> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        return factory;
    }   
 
}
```

application yaml

```
spring:
  kafka:
    #bootstrap-servers: ${kafka.bootstrap.servers}
    bootstrap-servers: <<broker address>>
    properties:
      security:
        protocol: SASL_SSL
      sasl:
        mechanism: OAUTHBEARER
        jaas:
          config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required;
        login:
          callback:
            handler:
              class: <<Security call back handler>>
      max.request.size: 750000
      request.timeout.ms: 30000
      linger.ms: 500
      delivery.timeout.ms: 91500
      metadata.max.age.ms: 180000
      connections.max.idle.ms: 60000
    consumer:          
      enable-auto-commit: false
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      properties:
        max.poll.records: 5
        partition.assignment.strategy: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor
    listener:
      type: single
      ack-mode: batch
```

KafkaListener configuration

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${my.kafka.conf.topics}'.split(',')}", concurrency = "${my.kafka.conf.concurrency}", clientIdPrefix = "${my.kafka.conf.clientIdPrefix}", groupId = "${my.kafka.conf.groupId}")
    public void kafkaListener(final Flight flight,@Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) Long offset,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) Integer partitionId,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) Long timestamp) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
```

Comment: Well, you only have `final Flight flight`. If you want a batch, did you mean `final List<Flight> flight`?

Comment: And the headers are Lists too, with the position in the list for each record matching the position of the payload in its list.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I figured it out from the documentation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at the documentation again, and you'll notice the argument to the listener parameters is a List object, not a singular entity of your deserialized type

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#batch-listeners

Comment: Yes, I figured it out yesterday. thank you so much though.. when we are setting  factory.setBatchListener(true); method annotated with @KafkaListener needs to take a List